# Error en Chrome al generar un pdf dinámico con FPDF y CakePhp

Tags: php, fpdf, cakephp

Tengo la siguiente url (https://midominio.com/pdf/cuota/25011/4) cuyos últimos 2 valores son parámetros, es decir, 25011 y 4 son parámetros. El problema es que en Chrome no descarga el pdf y envía el siguiente error "No se pudo cargar el documento PDF.", pero si envío la misma url sin parámetros, es decir (https://midominio.com/pdf/cuota), descarga correctamente el pdf, pero ya no sería dinámico.
En mozilla y safari descarga perfectamente el pdf con la url con parámetros.

Estoy trabajando con Cakephp 4 y FPDF para construir el pdf.

Espero su ayuda.

Comment: primero que nada te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: si el problema tubiera que ver con php, como podriamos evaluar el problema o decirte: hey aqui en esta linea falta algo ... por eso es aconsejable que agregues: [mre]